# Draw Image Outside of Layout in WPF

Tags: wpf, styles, wpf-controls, controltemplate

I'm creating a style to customize a RadioButton so that the RadioButton can display a star image behind the Bullet. I have the star being drawn with an ImageBrush as the background of a 20x20 grid that holds the Bullet layout. It's working fine, except I don't want the overall height of the RadioButton to be 20px tall. So I want to make the grid only 10x10 but still have the star 20x20 and centered behind the bullet (therefore the star's top left coordinate would be -5,-5 relative to the top left of grdBullet). How can I draw the star image behind or outside of the layout?

Excerpt of my style:

```
....
<ImageBrush x:Key="StarBrush" ImageSource="/Common;component/Resources/Images/FavoriteStar_FrontFacing_24x24_96.png" />
</Style.Resources>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
            <BulletDecorator VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                    <Grid Name="grdBullet" Height="20" Width="20" Background="{StaticResource StarBrush}">
                        <Grid Width="10" Height="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Ellipse Name="RadioOuter" Fill="#FFF4F4F4" Stroke="#FF8E8F8F" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                            <Ellipse Name="RadioInner" StrokeThickness="1" Margin="2" Fill="{StaticResource RadioInnerDefaultFill}" Stroke="{StaticResource RadioInnerDefaultStroke}" />
                            <Ellipse Name="RadioChecked" StrokeThickness=".75" Margin="2.5" Stroke="#FF193B55" Fill="{StaticResource RadioCheckedFill}" Visibility="Hidden" />
                            <Border CornerRadius="0" Margin="4" Name="RadioMark" Background="#FFADADAD" Visibility="Hidden" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </BulletDecorator.Bullet>

                <!--Text element-->
                <TextBlock Margin="3,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </TextBlock>
            </BulletDecorator>
....
```

Comment: Have you considered using a Canvas?  That allows you to render outside its bounds.

Comment: Do you mean `-5,-5` relative to the top left of grdBullet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two words: Negative margins.

```
<BulletDecorator.Bullet>
    <Grid Width="10" Height="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Rectangle Height="20" Width="20" Margin="-5" Fill="{StaticResource StarBrush}" />
        ...
    </Grid>
</BulletDecorator.Bullet>
```

For a more general purpose, you could set the `Margin` using a MultiValueConverter that returns a `Thickness`. For example, `Margin.Left` would be equal to `-(SelfWidth - ParentWidth) / 2`.

Comment: Aha. I had tried negative margin, but only on the left side which didn't give the intended result. Equal negative margin on both sides does it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can render anything anywhere with negative margins, no need for canvas. Try this (i have assumed -5,5 is center of image otherwise you need to put -15 15 or even -25 25

```
    <ImageBrush x:Key="StarBrush"
ImageSource="/Common;component/Resources/Images/FavoriteStar_FrontFacing_24x24_96.png"
Margin="-5 5 0 0" />
```

Comment: Thanks! That was on the right track except it doesn't constrain the size of the image to 20x20. I wrote -5,5 for the top left but it was supposed to be -5,-5.